# How to remove headings on certain pages only?

Tags: sectioning

I am trying to remove the heading on certain pages only like the appendix. Does anyone know, how to do this?

This is my code:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[headsepline,automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\rightmark}
\ofoot{\pagemark}
\addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\upshape\bfseries}
\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\bfseries}
\KOMAoptions{onpsinit=\setstretch{1}}
\renewcommand*\chaptermarkformat{}
\renewcommand*\chapterpagestyle{scrheadings}

\title{BSP}
\author{author}
\date{February 2021}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\section{f}
.....
\section{b}
.....
\section{d}


\end{document}
```

Comment: \thispagestyle{empty} or \thispagestyle{plain} should do it.  For the whole appendix, \pagestyle{...} after \appemdix.

Comment: See also \titlepagestyle \partpagestyle \chapterpagestyle \indexpagestyle (page 83 of KOMA manual).